# Indoor Navigation System by using "HERE"

Tags: javascript, java, sdk, navigation, indoor-positioning-system

I'm looking for a indoor navigation solution for a shopping mall. We actually need to do some modifications as well of the end product. Please find our to do integrations below,

1. Whether the shop is closed or not
2. Ability to Rate Shop Rating
3. Session Time Out (Time Limit to Access the Application - Reasonable time cap will be given to use the app, as well as Once the user leave the building he wont be able to access the maps)
4. Application will be ask for NIC and Full name before user sign in to the navigation system due to security reasons.

Just Need to verify is it possible to build the above notes with my chosen platform.

Platform - https://developer.here.com/products/indoor-positioning

Any suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, Indoor Positioning platforms provide basic functions like indoor/outdoor positioning, map management, Point of Interest.

All other functions should be developed by your mobile application or server-side app.

There are other providers of technology providers that you could check:

https://navigine.com/

https://indoo.rs/

https://www.infsoft.com/